# Fortran program does not converge without subroutine

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm using a Fortran 90 script below to solve a partial differential equation using iterative method, but I have one issue about the structure of the program. If I use a subroutine called by the program the solution converge properly, but if I just put the calculations inside of the iterations the solution does not converge.

Here is the program that does not work:

```
...
DO IT = 2,ITMAX
DO I = 1,IMAX
    PHIN(IT-1,I,1) = PHIN(IT-1,I,2) - (Y(2) - Y(1))*UINF*PHIY(I)
END DO

PHIN(IT,I,1) = PHIN(IT-1,I,1)

DO J = 2,JMAX-1
    DO I = 2,IMAX-1
        LPHI(I,J) = AX(I)*PHIN(IT-1,I-1,J) - &
                    BX(I)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J) + &
                    CX(I)*PHIN(IT-1,I+1,J) + &
                    AY(J)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J-1) - &
                    BY(J)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J) + &
                    CY(J)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J+1)
    ENDDO
ENDDO
!
! SELECT CASE(SOL)
!     CASE(1)
!       CALL NPJ()
!     CASE(2)
!       CALL NPGS()
!     CASE(3)
!       CALL NSOR()
! END SELECT

DO J = 2,JMAX-1
    DO I = 2,IMAX-1
        C(I,J) = 1/(2*(DELTAX(I)**2 + DELTAY(J)**2))* &
                 (((DELTAX(I)*DELTAY(J))**2)*LPHI(I,J) + &
                 (PHIN(IT,I-1,J) - PHIN(IT-1,I-1,J))*DELTAY(J) + &
                 (PHIN(IT,I,J-1) - PHIN(IT-1,I,J-1))*DELTAX(I))
    END DO
END DO

PHIN(IT,:,:) = PHIN(IT-1,:,:) + C(:,:)

RESI(IT) = MAXVAL(ABS(LPHI(:,:)))

IF (RESI(IT)<EPS) THEN
    ITVALUE = IT
        EXIT
ENDIF

LPHI(:,:) = 0

WRITE(*,*) IT,RESI(IT)
ENDDO
...
```

and the solution that works fine,

```
...
DO IT = 2,ITMAX
DO I = 1,IMAX
    PHIN(IT-1,I,1) = PHIN(IT-1,I,2) - (Y(2) - Y(1))*UINF*PHIY(I)
END DO

PHIN(IT,I,1) = PHIN(IT-1,I,1)

DO J = 2,JMAX-1
    DO I = 2,IMAX-1
        LPHI(I,J) = AX(I)*PHIN(IT-1,I-1,J) - &
                    BX(I)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J) + &
                    CX(I)*PHIN(IT-1,I+1,J) + &
                    AY(J)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J-1) - &
                    BY(J)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J) + &
                    CY(J)*PHIN(IT-1,I,J+1)
    ENDDO
ENDDO

SELECT CASE(SOL)
    CASE(1)
      CALL NPJ()
    CASE(2)
      CALL NPGS()
    CASE(3)
      CALL NSOR()
END SELECT

PHIN(IT,:,:) = PHIN(IT-1,:,:) + C(:,:)

RESI(IT) = MAXVAL(ABS(LPHI(:,:)))

IF (RESI(IT)<EPS) THEN
    ITVALUE = IT
        EXIT
ENDIF

LPHI(:,:) = 0

WRITE(*,*) IT,RESI(IT)
ENDDO
...


subroutIne NPGS()
use var_mesh
use var_solve

    C(:,:) = 0

    DO J = 2,JMAX-1
        DO I = 2,IMAX-1
            C(I,J) = 1/(2*(DELTAX(I)**2 + DELTAY(J)**2))* &
                     (((DELTAX(I)*DELTAY(J))**2)*LPHI(I,J) + &
                     (PHIN(IT,I-1,J) - PHIN(IT-1,I-1,J))*DELTAY(J) + &
                     (PHIN(IT,I,J-1) - PHIN(IT-1,I,J-1))*DELTAX(I))
        END DO
    END DO

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE NPGS
```

Can someone explain what is the main difference and why both programs are different?

Comment: Another difference. The original calls 3 different subroutines. I am guessing they handle the special boundary conditions. You do not implement them from what I see. Why would you step backward anyway? Subroutines are nice 'units' that do specific jobs for you.

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the welcome [tour]. It is good to always show your snippets with declarations of all your variables when you cannot show the whole program (complete programs are always preferred and sometimes required, see [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

Assigning C = 0 helps the script in the convergence, but I found what was the error, I assign just one part of the boundary condition in the program in this line:

`PHIN(IT,I,1) = PHIN(IT-1,I,1)`

but the correct way is to the entirely matrix and:

`PHIN(IT,:,:) = PHIN(IT-1,:,:)`

Comment: A bit of a semantics sidebar...

Scripting languages are not compiled, so fortran, C, assembly are NOT scripts.

Good job on the debug... It is a skill that is important !